# Azure Blob storage to Sharepoint online using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, csv, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to populate a Sharepoint Online list. The source files are of csv format and reside in Azure Blob storage. Is it possible to use Logic Apps to read the contents of the csv line by line (not copy/move files to Sharepoint) and insert a row in the Sharepoint list? I could not find any actions that would allow me to parse the csv files in Azure Logic Apps.

**Side note:** The csv files are being generated using an Azure Data Pipeline. I am only writing them to csv as ADF doesn't allow Sharepoint Online as a sink. If there is a way to directly populate the data to Sharepoint and avoid writing to a csv, then that would be magical!

Comment: have the Pipeline output the data in json instead of csv, then Logic App can process easily.

Comment: There’s a connector coming that will be available soon that will help you with this. You can still use it via REST calls if you’re really keen. If you want more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parse CSV` action of Plumsail, a 3rd party connector. Below is the flow of my logic app where I could able to insert each row from csv to SharePoint list.

[image]

Below is my CSV File in my storage

[image]

***RESULTS:***

[image]